# Using both AspNet.Identity and OpenConnectId(For Azure AD Signin)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

How am I able to make use of both OpenIdConnect(To authenticate with Azure AD) and also allow normal logging in using AspNet.Identity ?

I use the following is used in the `Startup.Auth` for OpenIdConnect:

```
// ConfigureAuth method  
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            //Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user

            //and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

                            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                            {
                                ClientId = clientId,
                                Authority = authority,
                                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                {
                                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                                    {
                                        context.HandleResponse();
                                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            });


        } // end - ConfigureAuth method
```

I use the following is used in the `Startup.Auth` for normal signing in(AspNet.Identity):

```
// ConfigureAuth method  
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //Configure the sign in cookie

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
        } // end - ConfigureAuth method
```

Using one or the other works, but If I combine them, such as the following:

```
// ConfigureAuth method  
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            //Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user

            //and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider

            //Configure the sign in cookie

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

                            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                            {
                                ClientId = clientId,
                                Authority = authority,
                                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                {
                                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                                    {
                                        context.HandleResponse();
                                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            });


        } // end - ConfigureAuth method
```

Then when I try authenticate with Azure AD, it seems as if it is looping during "redirect"(after signing in), and then after a while returns back to the sign in page and says "Cannot sign in". However, when logging in normally(using AspNet.Identity), then it logs in successfully.

I hope this makes sense - Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not sure if this is the right way, but I managed to get it working, but there is a down side, If I authenticate with Azure AD, then logging in the normal way(using aspnet.identity) always ends up logging in with the user that authenticated with AAD.

I added the following before the `app.UseCookieAuthentication` and then again just before the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`:

`app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);`

This is my code in the `Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            //Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user

            //and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider

            //Configure the sign in cookie

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

                            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                            {
                                ClientId = clientId,
                                Authority = authority,
                                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                {
                                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                                    {
                                        context.HandleResponse();
                                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                                    }
                                }
                            });


        } // end - ConfigureAuth method
```